# How to solve a system of differential equations using ode23 or ode45?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

$\dot{x}=v_x$

$\dot{y}=v_y$

$\dot{v_x}=\frac{Cx}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$

$\dot{v_y}=\frac{Cy}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$

where $C$ is a constant.

How is this solvable (assuming initial conditions are given)?

If I want to use something like

```
[t,y] = ode23(@f,tspan,initial_condition)
```

then what should my $f$ be?

Comment: Try this: http://www.math.tamu.edu/~phoward/m442/matode.pdf My prof wrote these notes for using the solvers.

Comment: Thank you, its a very good document.